# Pull imdbIDs for titles on search list

Tags: pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, imdb, imdbpy

Would it be possible to get all the IMDb IDs for titles that meet a search criteria (such as number of votes, language, release year, etc)?

My priority is to compile a list of all the IMDb IDs are classified as a feature film and have over 25,000 votes (a.k.a. those eligible appear on the top 250 list) as it appears [here](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&num_votes=25000,&title_type=feature&view=simple&sort=num_votes,desc). At the time of this posting, there are 4,296 films that meet that criteria.

(If you are unfamiliar with IMDb IDs: it is a unique 7-digit code associated with every film/person/character/etc in the database. For instance, for the movie ["Drive" (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0780504/?ref_=nv_sr_1), the IMDb ID is "`0780504`".)

However, in the future, it would be helpful to set the search criteria as I see fit, as I can when typing in the url address (with &num_votes=##, &year=##, &title_type=##, ...)

I have been using IMDBpy with great success to pull information on individual movie titles and would love if this search feature I describe were accessible through that library.

Until now, I have been generating random 7-digit-strings and testing to see if they meet my criteria, but this will be inefficient moving forward because I waste processing time on superfluous IDs.

```
from imdb import IMDb, IMDbError
import random
i =  IMDb(accessSystem='http')
movies = []
for _ in range(11000):
    randID = str(random.randint(0, 7221897)).zfill(7)
    movies.append(randID)

for m in movies:
    try:
        movie = i.get_movie(m)
    except IMDbError as err:
      print(err)`

    if str(movie)=='':
        continue

    kind = movie.get('kind')
    if kind != 'movie':
        continue

    votes=movie.get('votes')
    if votes == None:
        continue

    if votes>=25000:
```

Comment: you want your code to be efficient right

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.omdbapi.com/
You can use the API directly, to search by title or ID.

In python3

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=27939b55&s=moana").read()
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I would prefer not to search each title individually, I found a solution that would scrape all 4,296 IDs at once

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using Beautiful Soup based on a tutorial written by [Alexandru Olteanu](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-beautifulsoup/)

Here is my code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import math
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from warnings import warn

url = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?num_votes=25000,&title_type=feature&view=simple&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1&ref_=adv_nxt"
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

num_films_text = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'desc')
num_films=re.search('of (\d.+) titles',str(num_films_text[0])).group(1)
num_films=int(num_films.replace(',', ''))
print(num_films)

num_pages = math.ceil(num_films/50)
print(num_pages)

ids = []
start_time = time()
requests = 0

# For every page in the interval`
for page in range(1,num_pages+1):    
    # Make a get request    
    url = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?num_votes=25000,&title_type=feature&view=simple&sort=num_votes,desc&page="+str(page)+"&ref_=adv_nxt"
    response = get(url)

    # Pause the loop
    sleep(randint(8,15))  

    # Monitor the requests
    requests += 1
    sleep(randint(1,3))
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(requests, requests/elapsed_time))
    clear_output(wait = True) 

    # Throw a warning for non-200 status codes
    if response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))   

    # Break the loop if the number of requests is greater than expected
    if requests > num_pages:
        warn('Number of requests was greater than expected.')  
        break

    # Parse the content of the request with BeautifulSoup
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Select all the 50 movie containers from a single page
    movie_containers = page_html.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-simple')

    # Scrape the ID 
    for i in range(len(movie_containers)):
        id = re.search('tt(\d+)/',str(movie_containers[i].a)).group(1)
        ids.append(id)
print(ids)
```